Count number of cells based on a date in one column and a money value in another
I have column A with various dates over a year (these are full dates, not just months)
I have column B with financial savings figures (some of which will be 0 or blank - they can be either/or, whatever is easiest)
I want to get data, by month, that tells me the number of cells in column B that have a figure in there (or figure above 0).
Essentially, I want to know the success rate. So if in April there are 20 dates and 15 of this return a figure above 0 I want to be able to show that.
Can't work out at all what formula to use or if I can return anything via a pivot table.
Thank you.
I've not found anything that can work, maybe if I created some sub-tables it might help but tying to avoid that

Welcome to SO. Please provide some sample data (best by using Markdown Table Generator ) and your expected output - it is then much easier to help you. Reading [ask] and [repro] will help you to improve your question. Maybe this link will help you too: Stack Overflow question checklist.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Use COUNTIFS and Book-End the date desired:
=COUNTIFS(A:A,">="&DATE(2024,1,1),A:A,"<"&DATE(2024,2,1).B:B,">0")

This will count all values above 0 in January 2024

Thanks for the comment but that returns 0. Also, would that just return anything post 1st Jan? I' looking for month by month, Jan, Feb, March etc. Thank you

Then your dates may be text that look like dates and not true dates or your references need to modify to look at the correct columns.  This would count the entire month of January 2024 that have a value over 0. Without more information on your actual setup it is hard to know why you get 0.
